# Get scope identity from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL. I have to create a stored procedure with multiple insert statements. In which second insert statement expects first inserted row id.
And third insert statement expects second inserted row id. Below is my SQL statements,

```
INSERT INTO table1( ccc ) VALUES ( 'a' );   
SET scopeIdentity = LAST_INSERT_ID();    

INSERT INTO table2( ccc,tttId ) VALUES ( 'b',scopeIdentity );   
SET SET scopeIdentity2 = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 

INSERT INTO table3( ccc,tttId2 ) VALUES ( 'b',scopeIdentity2 );
```

Any suggessions most welcome!.

Thanks in Advance
Sangeetha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1( ccc ) VALUES ( 'a' );      

INSERT INTO table2( ccc,tttId ) VALUES ( 'b',LAST_INSERT_ID());    

INSERT INTO table3( ccc,tttId2 ) VALUES ( 'b',LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

ie, you dont have to set the value of [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in a variable and then insert the value using that variable.

Also check the [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-insert-id.html)

> - INSERT statements that store a value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column.    This is true whether the value is automatically generated by storing
>     the special values NULL or 0 into the column, or is an explicit
>     nonspecial value.
> - In the case of a multiple-row INSERT statement, the return value of    mysql_insert_id() depends on the MySQL server version.